# Error when ProGuard Enabled : Uncaught translation error

Tags: android, proguard, android-studio-2.0

Here is the the Message :

> :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :flurry_lib:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :googleCloudMessaging_lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :chartboostSDK:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :mainLibProj:compileJava UP-TO-DATE :mainLibProj:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :googleCloudMessaging_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :unityandroidresources:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   :mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :etcetera_lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE :iAB_lib:processResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :unityandroidresources:compileJava UP-TO-DATE :localytics_lib:jar
>   UP-TO-DATE :chartboostSDK:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :unityandroidresources:jar UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :localytics_lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :unityandroidresources:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :etcetera_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE :chartboostSDK:classes
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareReleaseDependencies :app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:collectReleaseMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :mainLibProj:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :googleCloudMessaging_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE :etcetera_lib:jar
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :googleCloudMessaging_lib:jar UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :iAB_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE :flurry_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :localytics_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :flurry_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :flurry_lib:processResources UP-TO-DATE :iAB_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :mainLibProj:classes
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE :mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534:jar
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE Information:Gradle tasks
>   [app:assembleRelease]
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease UP-TO-DATE
>   :etcetera_lib:compileJava UP-TO-DATE :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:checkReleaseManifest
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :chartboostSDK:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :localytics_lib:classes UP-TO-DATE :iAB_lib:jar UP-TO-DATE 1 error;
>   aborting Uncaught translation error:
>   com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException:
>   com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to
>   com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef Error:Execution failed
>   for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 1 Information:BUILD FAILED
> >     Information:Total time: 7.838 secs

Here is my buid.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.app_android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile project(':chartboostSDK')
    compile project(':flurry_lib')
    compile project(':googleCloudMessaging_lib')
    compile project(':mainLibProj')
    compile project(':localytics_lib')
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534')
    compile project(':unityandroidresources')
    compile project(':iAB_lib')
    compile project(':etcetera_lib')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/FlurryPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/FreshdeskPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/Prime31UnityActivity.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-bridge.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalar.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalarUnity3d.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost-adapter-1.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_4_3_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger.jar')
    compile files('libs/emojiplugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/nativex-adapter-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyunitywrapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
}
```

Comment: Every things looks seems, some time  Gradle not supports to JDK .Try to clean the project and  run again.

Comment: Tried it several times, but does not work :(